# Accessing Folder Contents In Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to access a folder in my codeigniter website, this is my directory map

```
--public_html
  --application
  --media
  --user_guide
```

I want to list my media folder using link like this.

```
https://example.com/media/
```

So i can list all my media files and folder using that link in codeigniter like

```
1. button.jpg 
2. button2.jpg
```

Once your click on the link can be able to view the file OR if folder should be able to see the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->load->helper('directory');

$map = directory_map('./media/');
```

Loop this $map and do your stuffs. the output of `print_r($map)` will be like bellow.

```
Array (
    [libraries] => Array
            (
                    [0] => benchmark.html
                    [1] => config.html
                    ["database/"] => Array
                            (
                                    [0] => query_builder.html
                                    [1] => binds.html
                                    [2] => configuration.html
                                    [3] => connecting.html
                                    [4] => examples.html
                                    [5] => fields.html
                                    [6] => index.html
                                    [7] => queries.html
                            )
                    [2] => email.html
                    [3] => file_uploading.html
                    [4] => image_lib.html
                    [5] => input.html
                    [6] => language.html
                    [7] => loader.html
                    [8] => pagination.html
                    [9] => uri.html
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using it like this every where:

```
<?php $yourFile = base_url()."media/button.jpg"; ?>
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `index.html` file inside your `media` folder, you can't see any of the files inside `media` folder in CodeIgniter.

So, If you want to view all the file inside the `media` folder, just delete `index` file.

Comment: how about controller ?
in view should like this ?
$this->load->view('media/'); OR $this->load->view('');

Comment: sorry. Can you make your question understandable?

Comment: If you want display all the file inside the `media` folder in view, then you should write code like this `<?php echo base_url().'media/button.jpg'; ?>`